Is this an irrefutable, tautogical proof that in the beginning, there was nothing?
IN THE BEGINNING, THERE WAS NOTHING:
If anything already existed, the beginning was earlier.
I'd also be curious to know of anyone has ever presented that in philosophical history. It seems like a pretty tight argument to me.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Zhuang-zi already beat you to it, some 2300 years ago:

雖然，請嘗言之。有始也者，有未始有始也者，有未始有夫未始有始也者。有有也者，有無也者，有未始有無也者，有未始有夫未始有無也者。俄而有無矣，而未知有無之果孰有孰無也。今我則已有謂矣，而未知吾所謂之其果有謂乎，其果無謂乎？
... But, allow me to try to say something about this. There is a
beginning. (So) there is (a) not yet having begun to be a beginning.
(So) there is (a) not yet having begun to not yet having begun to be a
beginning. There is (a) presence [being]. There is (an) absence
[non-being]. There is a not yet having begun to be absent [to not be
there]. There is a not yet having begun to not yet having begun to be
absent [to not be there]. Suddenly there is an absence [non-being].
But I (we) don't really know, in terms of being and non-being, what it
actually is, being or non-being. Now, I seem to have said something,
but I don't know if I've actually said something or didn't say
anything.

(Square brackets indicate an alternative translation.)
Now, the question is: Is this a confirmation of what @MissUnderstands wrote or a refutation?

+1. It is neither, it is one or both, or before one not the both, the one or the not the other.

Chuang Tzu! Classic!! This site could do with more of him. Alsi: I wrote here (maybe in too much detail) why everything here is Christian. It's refreshing to be proved wrong at least once in every thousand posts

In fact, Zs note is an attempt to come to grips with the infinite divisibility of time - in relation to being/non-being. This was in answer to the paradoxes of divisibility that his friend, the logician Hui Shi, had discovered, and which closely resemble Zeno's paradoxes. Zs conclusion seems to be that language is too indeterminate to express these things (and it definitely was before the invention of calculus).

Kafka: "Das Glück begreifen, daß der Boden, auf dem du stehst, nicht größer sein kann, als die zwei Füße ihn bedecken." (almost a literal quote of Zhuangzi) - If anything is my philosophical motto, this is it.

No. You can be simply misunderstanding or not correctly describing the system.
Say for an example that the "beginning" is when time starts so there is no "before" but what exists at the instant time starts is not nothing.
Relying on our intuitive language and logic that is deeply tied to our experience isn't good enough when describing systems that can have very little to do with our experience.

This is an obscure line of Hebrew scripture:

God put the timeless into their hearts, without men ever discovering, from beginning to end, the work which God has done.

If one is Godless then so be it. Instead of a mysterious and nameless God the source would be emptiness because all known concepts originate in the otherwise empty field of conscious awareness.
The direct experience of the empty field of awareness makes it clear that models of reality or what exists (ontology) arise and pass away in the stream of consciousness. The idea that things exist which correspond to what arises in the mind is a belief held in the mind which cannot be proven or disproven by getting outside the field of awareness. Emptiness is therefore a concept we associate with what exists at the source of the stream of consciousness.
